# for loop update model with string variable names

Tags: r

I have some complex model terms like restricted cubic splines and interactions. I want to run a loop where I produce a set of reduced models and test them against the full model.

The following code does not produce a reduced model at all. The reduced model is identical to the full model. How do I essentially paste these strings sequentially into the update() call?

```
vars <- list("x1", "rcs(x2, c(110, 90, 60, 30))*rcs(x3, c(50, 65, 80))", 
              "rcs(x4, c(8, 10, 12, 14, 16))"
)

for (i in vars) {
  reduced <- update(fit, . ~ . - as.name(i))
  print(reduced$sformula)
  lrtest(fit, reduced)
}
```

Comment: Please give a reproducible example so that code can be tried

Comment: You were using `terms` to assign an object, which is actually the name of the function `terms()`, better use `vars` or sth the like to avoid confusion; test names before using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Here is the fix for anyone who is struggling with the same:

```
for (i in terms) {
  formula_fit <- formula(fit)
  reduced_formula <- as.formula(paste(". ~ . -", i ))
  reduced <- update(fit, reduced_formula)
  print(lrtest(fit, reduced))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid superfluous code, do it in a one-liner. Using `lapply` gives a useful list to do something with.

```
lapply(setNames(vars, vars), \(i) lmtest::lrtest(fit, update(fit, sprintf(".~.-%s", i))))
```

If you just aim at the *p*-values, do

```
sapply(setNames(vars, vars), \(i) lmtest::lrtest(fit, update(fit, sprintf(".~.-%s", i)))[2, 5])
#        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt 
# 0.89528447 0.35977940 0.22843362 0.55351226 0.02034653 
#       qsec         vs         am       gear       carb 
# 0.17175451 0.85218023 0.13711271 0.58880330 0.76659590
```

`sapply` is `lapply` wrapped in `simplify2array`. Whether `sprintf` or `paste` is a matter of taste*.

<sub><sub>*that rhymes - lucky day!</sub></sub>

---

*Data:*

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ ., mtcars)
vars <- c("cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")
```